# DocX [Novacode] :: read paragraph magic text, identify font styles correctly

Tags: c#, docx, novacode-docx, paragraphs

Locals window shows no font styles for grouped magic texts although magic texts are grouped correctly.

The word document contains strike-though font styling that I can not identify with Novacode DocX..

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the StrikeThrough flag within the MagicText attribute. It's located at:

> paragraph.MagicText[index].formatting.StrikeThrough